# Why do warning and error log messages show and no others?

Tags: android

Background: I was trying to log some messages from an Android app that I am working on with a call to `log.d`. Logcat shows many messages, but none from my app. Finally I tried this:

```
// test logging
Log.e("taptimer debug", "debug message:program init:error");
Log.w("taptimer debug", "debug message:program init:warning");
Log.i("taptimer debug", "debug message:program init:info");
Log.d("taptimer debug", "debug message:program init:debug");
Log.v("taptimer debug", "debug message:program init:verbose");
Log.wtf("taptimer debug", "debug message:program init:what a terrible failure!");
System.out.println("Println debug:program init");
```

To my surprise, Logcat showed the messages from the warning and error levels. Why do those show and none of the others?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have an `ANDROID_LOG_TAGS` environment variable set?  Does `adb logcat` show you the full set of messages?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752645/where-are-logcat-filters-applied/14764756#14764756

Answer (score 0):

Select `verbose` as minimum log level in the menu:

[image]

Also, make sure you don't have a message filter on (left menu).

---

If it doesn't work, check the result of [`Log.isLoggable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).
If it returns false, you'll have to activate it manually with `adb`:

```
adb shell
setprop log.tag.taptimer VERBOSE
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do not have a filter set and verbose is selected in the dropdown. I still only get error and warning messages.